# Access bytecode created by Scala REPL

Tags: scala, bytecode, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any way to access the bytecode produced by REPL (i.e. the line of Scala you just typed and executed in REPL).

I need it for class loading to a remote node.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but in case it is, I'll tell you something about how it is structured: each time you execute a command, the REPL will create a new class. That new class contains exactly what you wrote, and it extends the old class.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this thread: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/4506. It may give you some ideas.

> Is there a way for me to use the findBytesForClassName to recover the original bytes of the class?  I'm trying to directly serialize REPL objects for parallelization to other JVMs and I can't use RMI.

Answer:

> Look at Javap.scala and then ILoop.scala.  The :javap command does 
>   exactly what you want.  The key is pathToFlatName.

It would require 2.9. The participants to that thread are also SO users...